# Activating and deactivating publishing feature breaks SP2010 wikis?

Tags: publishing, wiki, feature-activation

I have created an Enterprise Wiki site on SharePoint 2010.

I have added some pages to the wiki - that worked fine.

By default, it seems that an Enterprise Wiki has publishing turned off. If I activate the 'Publishing' site level feature, I can still add pages okay. But if I **then deactivate** the Publishing feature, this seems to completely and utterly break any wikis on the site:

- I can't create any new pages: I get an 'unexpected error', which has this in the ULS logs:

  System.ArgumentException: Invalid SPListItem. The SPListItem provided is not compatible with a Publishing Page.
- Even more strange: if I then re-activate the publishing feature, I can add new pages again, but for some reason it uses the 'body only' page template - you don't get the nice 'edit this page' link and modified by info at the top of the page, or the categories / ratings doen the right hand side.

Has anyone seen this before and can suggest a resolution? It looks like I will have to re-create the wiki site again and try migrating all the content over. I'm surprised that activating and deactivating the publishing feature will permanently wreack any wiki content? It seems reproducible so maybe can be classed as a bug, or at least there should be a health warning somewhere that you shoudl never activate publishing on wiki sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, this is how I resolved my dilemma:

- Copied all of the pages out of the broken wiki pages library (Open with windows explorer -> copy -> paste to a backup folder on my computer)
- Deleted the whole wiki site
- Created a new wiki site (with the same name etc.)
- Copied the old pages into the new site

And it all seems to work correctly again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I haven't an advice for you yet, but I can tell you that this is not normal behaviour, because we work with publishing features on our farm, activate them for a while (for migration from MOSS 2007) and deactivate them two or three times per month and our wiki pages are OK. Whole wiki pages and mini-wikies in libraries. Does unexpected error say something like "list does not exist" ? And if you check your content types, has some of them status (Invalid Associated Content Type) ? And publishing features are for SC and site separaely, site "SharePoint Server Publishing" enables web page gallery include wiki page I think.

Comment: The unexpected error says "The SPListItem provided is not compatible with a Publishing Page" in ULS (see question). I just checked out the content types of the wiki page library - it seems activating / deactivating publishing has added 3 content types to the library (Page, Aricle Page and Welcome Page). It has also removed a library settings menu 'Manage item scheduling' and added options for 'delete this document library' and 'save doc library as template'. Seems it's completely changed the wiki page library!

Comment: You can try to deaktivate/activate it manualy and see when the problem come up or just see what is happening

Comment: -> stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishing\feature.xml -url -force

-> stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishingresources\feature.xml -url -force

-> stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishingSite\feature.xml -url -force (activating on site collection level)

-> stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishingweb\feature.xml -url -force (activating on root site level)

-> stsadm -o activatefeature -filename publishinglayouts\feature.xml -url -force

-> stsadm -o activatefeature -filename navigation\feature.xml -url -force

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating pages? Are you using the "Create Page" command from the Site Actions menu? Publishing Pages must be created in the "Pages" library on a site, and the content types associated with the pages library will be publishing layouts (e.g. Article, Welcome, etc). Wiki pages are created in the SitePages library by default, and use a different base content type.

Can you create a Wiki page by browsing to the SitePages library and creating a new item from the New menu?