# Invalid SPListItem. The SPListItem provided is not compatible with a Publishing Page

Tags: error, splistitem

Whenever I try to save or publish or check in the web-interface, I get this error.

The test-environment did not have this issue, and I've only added a single web part to the page and tweaked the CSS a bit since moving to it to the live environment. Removing that single webpart does not make the error go away either.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try the solution mentioned over on this post?

[Activating and deactivating publishing feature breaks SP2010 wikis?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16035/activating-and-deactivating-publishing-feature-breaks-sp2010-wikis)

I don't know if it will work for you, but it might be worth a try.

I didn't have any success with that previous answer though and went the other way and delved into the bowels of SharePoint and found that even though I was re-activating the publishing features on my web I had to actually manually set the property __PublishingFeatureActivated to true with a console application.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
delegate
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Connecting to site...");
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(new Guid("d0c6ab0a-d112-41e2-bd03-a38219feca21")))
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Connecting to web...");
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/path/to/web"))
        {
            object test = web.GetProperty("__PublishingFeatureActivated");

            web.SetProperty("__PublishingFeatureActivated", "True");
            web.Properties.Update();
            web.Update();

            Console.Out.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Press any key to continue...");
            Console.In.Read();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Note for anyone browsing this answer - `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` has no effect in a Console App, it merely reverts the impersonating identity to the process identity and only really works within a web application.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error message, and the solution for me was to deactivate and reactivate the SharePoint Server Publishing **site** feature.

While doing that I ran into a second problem about not finding the content type `0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39`. The solution to that was to deactivate and reactivate the **site collection** feature Publishing Infrastructure.

Answer (score -1):

Deactivate and activate the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure at Site Collection level and SharePoint Server Publishing features at Site Level. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: As @torhovland said 3 years ago?